# I am not able to increase my ext4 partition size. How to do so?

Tags: linux, kali-linux

[image]

I have this kind of partitions. How can i increase the ext4 partition i have unallocated space just beside it but still it does let me increase the partition size

Comment: You need to move the partition to the beginning of the unused space. After that, you can expand it. According to its [home page](https://gparted.org/index.php), `gparted` is able to move partitions.

Comment: I am not able to move the partition to the beginning of the unused space. Pls help me

Comment: I am also not able to move your partition. I suggest you read the `gparted` and the `parted` manuals. However, it seems that the `move` command is not present in `parted` anymore after version 2.4.

Comment: A simple approach would be to create a backup, delete the partition, recreate it at the beginning of the unallocated space and restore the backup.

Comment: I got it right. The space has increased...... Sry to bother you

Comment: No bother at all, but how did you do it in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gparted can expand the partition to use the free space to the left, but the partition must not be mounted at the time in order to do this, so assuming that is your root partition, you will need to boot from removable media to run gparted.